# Probability (difficult)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, mathematical-optimization

An insurance company receives two claims. Each claim amount is continuously
between \$200 and \$700 with uniform probability and independent of each other：

(i) What is the probability that the larger claim amount is at least \$300?

(ii) What is the probability that the smaller claim amount is at most \$300?

(iii) What is the probability that the larger claim amount is at least \$500 given that thesmaller claim amount is at least \$400?

(iv) What is the probability that the larger claim amount is at most \$500 given that thesmaller claim amount is at most \$400?

(v) What is the probability that the larger claim amount is at least \$500 given that the smaller claim amount is at most \$300?

---

I work out the first two questions by the complementary events, but I am stuck in the iii）

Comment: Are you sure that you are on the proper site? This site is for the Mathematica (Wolfram) software language. Perhaps you want [`Mathematics StackExchange`](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You might also want to show what you've tried. People tend to be much more willing to help if you can show that you've made the effort yourself.

Comment: okok! I have already post it!

Comment: I think the question would be relevant and interesting here if (a) you asked just one component of it (e.g. part iii) --- at the present, it looks like a homework exercise that the OP is seeking others to do for you;   and (b) posed it in a _Mathematica_ context which may be of genuine interest here.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the question does concern Mathematica. The answers confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i)

```
Probability[z >= 300,z \[Distributed]TransformedDistribution[Max[x, y],
{x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{200, 700}], 
y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{200, 700}]}]]
```

> 24/25

(ii)

```
Probability[u <= 300, u \[Distributed] TransformedDistribution[Min[x,y],
{x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{200, 700}],
y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{200, 700}]}]]
```

> 9/25

(iii) Unfortunately,

```
Probability[z >= 500 \[Conditioned] u >= 400,
{z \[Distributed] TransformedDistribution[Max[x, y],
 {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{200, 700}], 
y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{200, 700}]}],u \[Distributed] 
   TransformedDistribution[
Min[x, y], {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{200, 700}], 
 y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{200, 700}]}]}]
```

returns the input.

Answer (score 1):

(i) and (ii) were already answered by user64494. (iii), (iv), and (v) can be solved by applying the definition of conditional probability: $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$

```
dist = {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{200, 700}], y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{200, 700}]};

problem3 = Probability[((x > y && x > 500) || (y > x && y > 500))
    && (x > 400 && y > 400), dist]/Probability[x > 400 && y > 400, dist]

problem4 = Probability[((x > y && x < 500) || (y > x && y < 500))
    && (x < 400 || y < 400), dist]/Probability[x < 400 || y < 400, dist]

problem5 = Probability[((x > y && x > 500) || (y > x && y > 500))
    && (x < 300 || y < 300), dist]/Probability[x < 300 || y < 300, dist]
```

Since these are uniformly distributed, these results can be visualized as well. For example, for problem 5:

```
RegionPlot[{((x > y && x > 500) || (y > x && y > 500))
    && (x < 300 || y < 300), x < 300 || y < 300},
    {x, 200, 700}, {y, 200, 700}]
```

Comment: Something to adjust: problem3 results $8/9 $, but the denominator should be equal $25$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Due to how conditional probabilities works, not necessarily. Run the RegionPlot command above and notice the overlap of the blue and the orange areas. The orange area represents the condition we already know to be met, while the blue area represents the condition we wish to know about. Due to the condition we've already applied though, this means that we already know the variables aren't in the entire space, so the denominator is smaller (usually 9 in these problems).

Comment: Sorry, don't understand it. Could you elaborate your answer? I obtain $16/25$ for your problem3, making use of another soft.

Comment: `RegionPlot[{((x > 500) || y > 500) && (x > 400 && y > 400), (x > 400 && y > 400)}, {x, 200, 700}, {y, 200, 700}]` The condition is guaranteed to be true, so the space is limited to the orange square automatically. The blue area is the area in which the question is solved. Thus, $8/9$ of the area meets the question's requirements.

Comment: Another way to proceed (that avoids having to compute the separate x >y and y > x possibilities) is to find the joint pdf of the smaller and larger values, for instance, using order statistics.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your (x > 400 && y > 400), (x > 400 && 
   y > 400). Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: `RegionPlot` is being used there to plot two separate regions. The first is attached to the first (x>400 AND y>400), which is the given condition that we already know to be met, so we are actually working in a space within the overall uniform distribution. In this space, the question is solved if (x>500 OR y>500). We also automatically know that x<700 and y<700. Since it's still uniformly distributed, that means that $8/9$ of the space answers the question.

Comment: Sorry, but your  plot of $\max(x,y) \ge 500$ is not correct. This is $[200,700]^2\setminus [200,500]^2$.